# Form error even when filled in

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms

I'm using a ModelForm and had this working perfectly. A user is creating several objects in succession, with each object having the preceding one in a Foreign Key relation. This had been working beautifully, but it suddenly broke, and I'm not sure what I did. The problem seems to be that one of the fields keeps raising an error indicating that it is not filled in, even though it is. I'm rendering the fields {{ .as_hidden }} and passing an initial value so users can't change their values, but if I have the form print it indicates that before I test to see if it's valid, I can see that the fields that are given initial values do indeed have those initial values.

Here's the view:

```
def new2(request, number):
  if not (request.user.is_authenticated()):
    return render(request, 'denied.html', {'message': 'You must log in before you can make a new entry.'})
  po=PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number)
  today = datetime.date.today()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WorkflowForm(request.POST, initial={'purchase1': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number), 'state': 'request', 'date_created': today})
    if form.is_valid():
      new_flow = form.save()
      addresses = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Operations').values_list('email', flat=True)      
      email = EmailMessage('New Workflow Entry',
               get_template('new-workflow-email.html').render(
                 Context({
                   'ponumber': new_flow.purchase.po_number,
                   'user': new_flow.purchase.user,
                   'customer': new_flow.purchase.customer,
                   'pk': new_flow.pk,
                   })
                 ),
                 to = addresses)
      print ('Sending email')
      email.send()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/list/request/')
    else:
      return render(request, 'new-workflow.html', {'form': form, 'purchase': po})
  else:
    form = WorkflowForm(initial={'purchase1': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number), 'state': 'request', 'date_created': today})
    return render(request, 'new-workflow.html', {'form': form, 'purchase': po, 'type': 'New'})
```

What's doubly odd is that after `if form.is_valid():` is called, the form *doesn't* have its initial values set correctly.

I don't know if the form will be helpful, but here it is just in case.

```
class WorkflowForm(ModelForm):
  purchase1=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=PurchaseOrder.objects.all(), required=False)
  purchase2=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Phase2.objects.all(), required=False)
  details = forms.CharField(required=False)


  date_created=forms.DateField(required=False)
  date_approved=forms.DateField(required=False)


  class Meta:
    model = POObject
```

In case its not clear, the user doesn't add any information at this stage--it's either `Accept` or `Edit`, with edit allowing the user to edit the information added in the previous stage. Can anyone offer any advice as to why this isn't working? Or what I need to do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What does your model for POObject look like?  Since you've declared all your custom form fields to not be required, if you're getting an error about a required field not being present it's probably one of the automatic fields derived from the POObject model.

Comment: I didn't include the model because, like I said, all of the fields are being set in the `initial={ ... }` phrase. The field that's still required is `state`, but as you can see above, it's being given a value when the form is instantiated.

Comment: Well, as noted that won't help when you're binding to the POST data.  If there's no way to edit `state`, don't include it in the form.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it was bad design. It's just weird that it was working before, and suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) is quite explicit about this:

> These [initial] values are only displayed for unbound forms, and they’re not used as fallback values if a particular value isn’t provided.

I'm not sure what the point is of including the fields as "hidden" but then filling them in on instantiation. If you don't want the fields in the form, exclude them and set them on the model instance itself:

```
class WorkflowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('purchase1', 'state', 'date_created')


...

if form.is_valid():
    new_flow = form.save(commit=False)
    new_flow.state = 'request'
    new_flow.purchase1 = po
    new_flow.save()
```

Comment: Yeah... That fixed it. Strange, it was working two days ago, don't know why it decided to stop working now.